# Virtual hosts inside virtual box

Tags: windows-xp, wamp, virtualbox, virtualhost

I've just installed virtual box along with windows xp to test websites in the all mighty IE 8 and below.

My default gateway on VB is 10.0.2.2 which shows my wamp homepage from host desktop.
On the hostdesktop I have:

```
127.0.0.1      test.com
which points to wamp/www/test in config
```

How do I get virtual box windows xp to takes me to the right location test.com? I've tried editing the windowsxp hosts file to add `10.0.2.2 test.com`

(`10.0.2.2/test` takes me to the page but is untestable because resources are relative to test.com)

Comment: what type of network adapter are you using?

Comment: Just fixed it, apparently 127.0.0.1 works on the virtual host to carry through to main computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you host PC has an ip in the 192.168.x.x range.

If thats the case you can change the VM's Network settings so Adapter1 is set to

```
Attached to:    Bridged Adapter
Name:           Realtec PCIe GBE Family Controller
Adapter Type:   Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop
Promiscuous Mode: Deny
Mac Address:     ????????
```

This for me made the VM part of the same subnet and allowed easy access to the host

So if your host IP is lets say 192.168.0.20 and your VB has a dynamically allocated 192.168.0.100

You can set yout HOSTS file on the VB as you might more readily expect

```
192.168.0.20  test.com
```